# Class for finding the median of a two-dimensional space

Tags: java, performance, static, coordinate-system, apache-spark

I have a simple static class that it's purpose is given an RDD of `Point` to find the median of each dimension and return that as a new `Point` using Spark's reduce functions.

**This is the class:**

```
public class MedianPointFinder {

    public static Point findMedianPoint(JavaRDD<Point> points) {
        Point biggestPointByXDimension = points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByXDimension(a, b));
        Point biggestPointByYDimension = points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByYDimension(a, b));

        double xDimensionMedian = biggestPointByXDimension.getX() / 2.0;
        double yDimensionMedian = biggestPointByYDimension.getY() / 2.0;

        return new Point(xDimensionMedian, yDimensionMedian);
    }

    private static Point getBiggestPointByXDimension(Point first, Point second) {
        return first.getX() > second.getX() ? first : second;
    }

    private static Point getBiggestPointByYDimension(Point first, Point second) {
        return first.getY() > second.getY() ? first : second;
    }
}
```

`Point` class is a simple class for storing an *(x, y)* point.

Comment: My understanding of median is the middle element out of N elements if the N elements were sorted.  You are finding the highest element and dividing its value by 2.  Is that what you really meant to do?  For example, given three x coordinates `1 2 9` I consider the median to be `2` not `4.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `Point` is not a [java.awt.Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) since that holds `x` and `y` as `int` and you're using `double`.

Why not getting rid of your `Point` class by making the "Finder" class itself a `MedianPoint`?

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class MedianPoint extends Point2D.Double {

  public MedianPoint(JavaRDD<Point> points) {
    super(
      /* your x calculation */,
      /* your y calculation */
      );
  }

  private static Point2D.Double greaterByXOf(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
    // ...
  }

  private static Point2D.Double greaterByYOf(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
    // ...
  }

} // MedianPoint
```

Comment: I do need my `Point` class for some methods that I have created in it that does not exist in Point2D but I guess what I could do is wrap `Point2D` with my `Point` class and then do `MedianPoint extends Point`.

Comment: Are there other reasons why you have to stick to `Point`? Which make moving `Point`'s methods into `MedianPoint` impossible?

Comment: No, not really. I just have it for providing a limited API and adding some functionality. I have posted my revised `Point` class here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70902/point2d-double-wrapper