# Point2D.Double wrapper

Tags: java, wrapper

I have made a `Point2D.Double` wrapper so I can add my own functionality (like a `dominate` method) and alter some (like `toString`) and control some (like not having public access to x and y).

**`Point` class:**

```
public class Point implements Serializable {

    private final Point2D.Double point2D;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.point2D = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    public Point(String line, String delimiter) {
        line = line.trim();
        String[] lineArray = line.split(delimiter);
        double x = Double.parseDouble(lineArray[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(lineArray[1]);
        this.point2D = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    public boolean dominates(Point point) {
        return (this.getX() <= point.getX() && this.getY() < point.getY()) 
                || (this.getY() <= point.getY() && this.getX() < point.getX());
    }

    public double getX() {
        return point2D.getX();
    }

    public double getY() {
        return point2D.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return point2D.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return point2D.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append('(').append(point2D.getX()).append(", ").append(point2D.getY()).append(')');
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you would like to get feedback about? Also why not `extends Point2D.Double`?

Comment: @Nihathrael naming conventions, method separation, proper clean usage of `equals` and `hashcode` in case of wrapper, possible other ways I can do this that are cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look and came up with a couple of suggestions:

**Extend rather than wrap**

I think it will be more useful if you extend the `Point2D.Double` class, instead of writing a wrapper around it. This way you will be able to use your custom point class everywhere that a normal `Point2D.Double` is expected. It also spares you from implementing and overriding many of the `Double`'s methods like `getX()` and the `hashCode()` and `toString()` methods.

**Use static method for construction from line**

When subclassing `Double` it is not possible to have a constructor that takes a line, does some calculations and then calls `super()`, as `super` has to be the first call in the constructor. Therefor we need to add a static utility class to create a `Point` from a line. See the `fromLine()` method below.

I think this is not a problem, as it leads to very readable line:

```
Point start = Point.fromLine(line);
```

**Documentation**

Your code does not include any documentation in form of comments, so that for example the input format for the `fromLine()` function is not entirely clear. Also it only uses one point from a line (which should be two points?), so maybe it should be called `fromLineStart()` or `fromLineEnd()` depending on which you mean.

**Class Naming**

The current name `Point` doesn't tell us a lot about what the class does. Maybe use something a little more descriptive like `PointDouble2D`? Maybe add some indication as that it does more than the normal Point2D.Double, by naming it: `PointDouble2DAdvanced` or something like that, not totally sure myself :)

**Final Result**

Here is the entire code example, without documentation comments:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class PointDouble2D extends Point2D.Double {

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public boolean dominates(Point2D.Double point) {
        return (getX() <= point.getX() && getY() < point.getY())
                || (getY() <= point.getY() && getX() < point.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append('(').append(getX()).append(", ").append(getY())
                .append(')');
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static PointDouble2D fromLineStart(String line, String delimiter) {
        line = line.trim();
        String[] lineArray = line.split(delimiter);
        double x = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(lineArray[0]);
        double y = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(lineArray[1]);
        return new PointDouble2D(x, y);
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: I too suggested to extend at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70878/58906 but OP apparently didn't like it. Do you have another idea how we can convince him not re-inventing the `Point2D.Double`-wheel?

Comment: In case he wants to limit the API, that could be a valid reason. But since all methods except for `setLocation` of the original `Point2D.Double` are implemented in the wrapper, I do not see any benefit  of having a wrapper. Especially as extending the class makes the new `PointDouble2D` easier to use, uses less code and provides more flexibility of use for the `PointDouble2D` class.

Comment: @GeroldBroser `Point2D.Double` gives public access to `x` and `y`. I don't want that, it can easily cause problems and it is completely unnecessary for what I am doing. It also is inconsistent with the style of my code therefore can easily cause future users/readers of my `Point` class to get confused or use it wrong. That is my only gripe, the `x` and `y` being public.

Comment: @Nihathrael like I said to Gerold my problem with extending is that I will have two public variables that can cause problems and confusion. That is my only problem.

Comment: @Nihathrael for some clarification: `fromLine()` would actually be used to read the (x,y) coordinates separated by a delimiter on a text file. It is not an actual line (vector). I should probably rename it to `textLine` or something along those lines. Also I will consider on making it an extension in both my questions, the only thing bugging me is the public x and y coordinates.

Comment: @DimitrisK I agree that having the `x` and `y` public is not very nice. I don't think I'd go through the hassle of not extending `Point2D.Double` though, as this is a general Problem with the `Point2D.Double`. This is of course unless you are designing a public API (which is to be released and used as such [think: apache commons]), then using a wrapper is probably worth considering. But for "private" or "in project"  use, I'd probably go with the simplistic approach of subclassing it.

Comment: This is mostly for project use so I guess you are right and I should extend it rather than wrap it both in this case and my other question.