# Coding on Point interfaces/superclasses instead of implementations

Tags: java, classes, coordinate-system

From pretty much any book I've read it always said to code on interfaces/superclasses and rarely on implementations, today though that advice made a bit confused about how I should format my code.

#### Questions:

1. Should I be using `Point2DAdvanced` or `Point2D.Double` in the the methods of `MedianPoint` (like JavaRDD<>, the 2 private methods, the variables)? Same goes for `FlagPointPairProducer`.
2. Should I be using `MedianPoint` or `Point2D.Double` in the `FlagPointPairProducer` class?
3. Should I store the `MedianPoint` from the static method in a `MedianPoint` or `Point2D.Double`?

#### The Code:

First off I have a `MedianPoint` class which extends `Point2D.Double`. This class is responsible for outputting a median point out of a collection of points (for now only an RDD).

```
public class MedianPoint extends Point2D.Double {

    public MedianPoint(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
    
    public static MedianPoint fromPointRDD(JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> points) {
        Point2DAdvanced biggestPointByXDimension = points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByXDimension(a, b));
        Point2DAdvanced biggestPointByYDimension = points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByYDimension(a, b));

        double xDimensionMedian = biggestPointByXDimension.getX() / 2.0;
        double yDimensionMedian = biggestPointByYDimension.getY() / 2.0;

        return new MedianPoint(xDimensionMedian, yDimensionMedian);
    }

    private static Point2DAdvanced getBiggestPointByXDimension(Point2DAdvanced first, Point2DAdvanced second) {
        return first.getX() > second.getX() ? first : second;
    }

    private static Point2DAdvanced getBiggestPointByYDimension(Point2DAdvanced first, Point2DAdvanced second) {
        return first.getY() > second.getY() ? first : second;
    }
}
```

I also have a `FlagPointPairProducer` class which according to a median point it calculates a subspace flag for a given `Point2DAdvanced` (another `Point2D.Double` extension) and returns a tuple of the flag and the point.

```
public class FlagPointPairProducer implements Serializable {

    private final Point2D.Double medianPoint;

    public FlagPointPairProducer(Point2D.Double medianPoint) {
        this.medianPoint = medianPoint;
    }

    public Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> getFlagPointPair(Point2DAdvanced point) {
        PointFlag flag = calculateFlag(point);
        return new Tuple2<>(flag, point);
    }

    private PointFlag calculateFlag(Point2DAdvanced point) {
        double x = point.getX();
        double y = point.getY();
        double medianX = medianPoint.getX();
        double medianY = medianPoint.getY();

        int xBit = x < medianX ? 0 : 1;
        int yBit = y < medianY ? 0 : 1;

        return new PointFlag(xBit, yBit);
    }
}
```

So I can initialize a `FlagPointPairProducer` like so:

```
Point2D.Double medianPoint = MedianPoint.fromPointRDD(points);
FlagPointPairProducer producer = new FlagPointPairProducer(medianPoint);
```

---

**Code requested for `Point2DAdvanced`:**

```
public class Point2DAdvanced extends Point2D.Double implements Serializable {

    public Point2DAdvanced(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public boolean dominates(Point2D.Double point) {
        return (x <= point.getX() && y < point.getY())
                || (y <= point.getY() && x < point.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append('(').append(x).append(", ").append(y).append(')');
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static Point2DAdvanced fromTextLine(String textLine, String delimiter) {
        textLine = textLine.trim();
        String[] lineArray = textLine.split(delimiter);
        double x = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(lineArray[0]);
        double y = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(lineArray[1]);
        return new Point2DAdvanced(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having static `fromPointRDD()`? That's not what has been suggested to you in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70878/58906 and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70905/58906. You commented _"This is mostly for project use so I guess you are right and I should extend it rather than wrap it both in this case and my other question."_ But you still have `Point2Advanced` (which is your former 'Point' I guess) the methods of which can be moved into `MedianPoint`.

Comment: With the stacic `fromPointRDD()` deriving `MedianPoint` from `Point2D.Double` doesn't make sense. You could use a bare `Point2D.Double`instead.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I have it as static so it can be consistent with Nihathrael's answer (I like the way he solved the `super()` issue). The methods of `Point2DAdvanced` can't be moved to `MedianPoint`, these two classes have an entirely different purpose. One cares about point domination issues and the other cares about being the median point of a collection. But if you have a suggestion feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Can you supply the code of `Point2DAdvanced` as well?

Comment: @GeroldBroser sure (I edited it in).

Comment: _"One cares about point domination issues and the other cares about being the median point of a collection."_ The question is less "what does it care about" but more "what **is** it". Both are a `Point2D` with two coordinates. You construct one by giving two coordinates. You construct the other by giving two coordinates (that have been calculated from a `JavaRDD` before in `fromPointRDD()`). The only difference is the `dominates(...)` method. I'm not sure whether this is enough difference to justify an extra class. Is it absolutely impossible that one `MedianPoint` can dominate another one?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I am following the single responsibility principle. If I mash the two classes together I will have two responsibilities in the same class, one for how a point dominates another and one for how to create a median point. Also by having a separate `MedianPoint` class I ensure that the point that `FlagPointPairProducer` takes as an input is definitely correctly initialized as a median point and is not any random point.

Comment: I agree in principle but this doesn't answer my question _"Is it absolutely impossible that one MedianPoint can dominate another one?"_

Comment: @GeroldBroser Oh sorry I forgot to answer to that. Yes it is definitely possible but a `MedianPoint` would never get used that way (to check for dominance). `MedianPoint` is only used in the `FlagPointPairProducer` and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is not to be taken lightly. Have you considered composition instead?

The MedianPoint class seems to represent a point that happens to be median in some collection of points. But this depends on the context. There is nothing in this class that could prevent creating points that are not in fact at the median. You can certainly call the constructor or a factory method with parameters that don't correspond to a median point. As such, it would make more sense to use regular point objects, and distinguish them from non-median points by naming.

The methods in this class can be static methods in a PointUtils good old fashioned utility class.

The same goes for Point2DAdvanced as well. So the answer to all your questions: use Point2D.Double everywhere. The custom point classes don't really add value, and do nothing to help reducing complexity.

Comment: MedianPoint is more of a "approximate median point" from a collection sometimes. Meaning I added a constructor which hardcodes x and y because the computation of median is sometimes quite an overhead to the skyline algorithm itself and many times it is very close to (5, 5) so I left the option to hardcode it in order to measure efficiency later down the line.

Comment: As for having a static utility class in place of extending seems a bit of a downgrade to me? I don't know, I am not an awfully experienced developer so I am probably wrong on that but I have always been avoiding static utility classes... I am wrong on that? I can certainly see the advantage in this case (shoving both median function and `dominates` in a simple utility class) it just feels a bit "weird".

Comment: Also one question. Say I use `Point2D.Double` exclusively and scrap `Point2DAdvanced`. Should I then just use `Point2D` like so `Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);` for declaration since I only care about x and y?

Comment: It's best to program against the most general interfaces that make sense in your logic. If your code works fine by using `Point2D` in all type declarations and signatures without ever having to cast to `Point2D.Double`, then by all means use `Point2D`. Utility classes are not great, but perfectly acceptable for *pure functions* that don't depend on state, only depend on the method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then no need for a `Point2DAdvanced`:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * ...
 */
public class MedianPoint extends Point2D.Double {

  /**
   * ...
   */
  public static MedianPoint from( String twoDoubles, String limit ) {
    // no need to trim since Double.parseDouble(...) below trims anyway
    String[] doubles = twoDoubles.split( limit );
    // Note from Double.valueOf(...):
    //   "To interpret localized string representations 
    //    of a floating-point value, use subclasses of NumberFormat." 
    return new MedianPoint(
      java.lang.Double.parseDouble( doubles[0] ),
      java.lang.Double.parseDouble( doubles[1] )
      );
    }

  /**
   * ...
   */
  private static Point2D.Double greaterByXOf( Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2 ) {
    return p1.getX() > p2.getX() ? p1 : p2;
    }

  /**
   * ...
   */
  private static Point2D.Double greaterByYOf( Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2 ) {
    return p1.getY() > p2.getY() ? p1 : p2;
    }

  /**
   * ...
   */
  public MedianPoint( double x, double y ) {
    super( x, y );
    }

  /**
   * ...
   */
  public MedianPoint(JavaRDD<Point2D.Double> points) {
    super(
      points.reduce((a, b) -> greaterByXOf(a, b)).getX() / 2.0,
      points.reduce((a, b) -> greaterByYOf(a, b)).getY() / 2.0;
      );
    }

  /**
   * ...
   */
  public boolean dominates( Point2D.Double point ) {
    return x <= point.getX() && y < point.getY() ||
           y <= point.getY() && x < point.getX();
    }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format( "(%f,%f)", x, y );
    }

  } // MedianPoint
```

Does this fit your needs?

If you're not happy with the class' name `MedianPoint` (because it **is** not such) rename it to something that suits you better.

Comment: I think it looks good this way as well.

Comment: Oh by the way the trimming is needed because if the string has any extra space the the doubles array will have 3 elements or more instead of two.

Comment: You're right if you allow whitespace characters for the delimiter. But then you have the same problem if the string looks like `"1.0␣␣2.0"` and the delimiter is a space.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions come in mind:

- Q: What behavior adds `MedianPoint` to `Point2D.Double`.
- A: None. The static methods do not, and there's nothing else.
- Q: How can I tell a `MedianPoint` from an ordinary `Point2D.Double`.
- A: Nothing but `instanceof` check. There's nothing special about it.
- Q: So why `MedianPoint extends Point2D.Double`?
- A: It's wrong. It should be a factory (method or class).

---

```
double xDimensionMedian = biggestPointByXDimension.getX() / 2.0;
```

"Half of the maximum" is surely not the definition of median I've been taught.

---

```
private final Point2D.Double medianPoint;
```

This seems to confirm the above. A `medianPoint` is just a `Point2D.Double`.

---

```
int xBit = x < medianX ? 0 : 1;
int yBit = y < medianY ? 0 : 1;
return new PointFlag(xBit, yBit);
```

Why not `boolean`?

---

`Point2DAdvanced`:

It's nice to add some functionality to a class, but it's not possible to do it for an object. So in order to be able to use `dominates`, you need to forget about the existing `Point2D.Double` and create a new object. IMHO too impractical.

This gets worsened by the fact that `Point2D.Double` is mutable. You may call `dominates` at a point when the original has changed. This may be what you want or not, but usually it's confusing at best. IMHO it was a mistake to make `Point2D.Double` mutable and I'd avoid it completely.

If you really want to use `Point2DAdvanced` as is, then you should probably provide a constructor or a factory taking a `Point2D.Double`. If you're only reusing part the `Point2D.Double`'s functionality, then it's probably not worth it.

Comment: About median, it is more a median of each dimension stored in a point rather than the median of the whole space. Specifically I am using the **D & C** algorithm in order to partition the data in 2^d parts (where d is the number of dimensions therefore 4 parts in my case). The median of each dimension is the point of division. For more details you can see this paper on page 4, third paragraph http://delab.csd.auth.gr/~apostol/thesis1.pdf

Comment: As for `PointFlag` boolean would not represent really well what xBit and yBit represent (the fact that 0 means they are lower and 1 means they are higher). As for the rest you are right I will consider not using `Point2D.Double`.